# Python how to use "try:" not stop when it raises except

Tags: python, optimization

I have this code and would like to shorten it. Is this anyway possible? Does not make that much sense to have that often the same code:

```html
try:
  years = values['year']
except KeyError:
  pass

try:
  tracks = values['track']
except KeyError:
  pass

try:
  statuses = values['status']
except KeyError:
  pass
```

Comment: That's what functions are for.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about avoiding the exceptions entirely?

`.get()` allows you to provide a default value if they key doesn't exist already...

```
years = values.get('year')  # Implicitly default to None
tracks = values.get('track', None)  # Explicitly default to None
statuses = values.get('status', 'Unknown')  # Or use any custom value
```

As mentioned in comments by [@DSM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/487339/dsm), this differs from your code in that it guarantees all variables will be bound with *some* value. Otherwise, attempting to use any of the variables might result in a `NameError` at run time.

Less efficient, but you can also explicitly check if a key exists...

```
if 'year' in values:
    # do something
```

Comment: This code differs from the OP's, and is much better, in that it guarantees that all three names will be bound.  The OP would need to bracket different parts of his code with `try/except NameError:`, which is.. inelegant.  (Myself, I'd just use the default None instead of 0 for years and tracks, but that one's at least arguable.)

Comment: @DSM Yeah, I was on the fence about which defaults to provide. I went with `0` as it was an integer value and unlikely to be a _valid_ value, however, I'd probably use Nones myself too...

Comment: this. do this. and get in the habit of doing this for the sake of your readability

Comment: Thats exactly what i was looking for! Thank you @Basic and @DSM!!

Answer (score -1):

Here you go.

```
try:
  years = values['year']
  tracks = values['track']
  statuses = values['status']
except KeyError:
  pass
```

Comment: This is not good because it will stop execution as soon as an exception is raised, possibly ignoring keys that do exist.

Comment: @BenBeirut While that is true, you don't know that that is a good or bad thing.  If it fails on one value does that crash the program?  If so then this is just fine.

Comment: We assume the OP wishes to refactor their code, not change its logic.

Comment: @BenBeirut if that is supposed to be the assumption then you are probably correct.

Comment: Yes @BenBeirut is right - i do not want to change the logic of the code